# Enum with associated value as associated value of another enum (nested associated value)

Tags: swift

I have enum `Foo` with associated value. Enum `Foo` serves as an associated value of another enum, `Car`. I would like to know how to access the 'nested' associated value of `Foo`, as shown in the example below:

```
enum Foo: Equatable {
    case moo
    case zoo(String)
}

enum Car {
     case mar
     case dar(Foo)
     case gar(Foo)
}

func request(with type: Car) -> String {
     switch type {
     case .mar:
         return "mar"
     case .dar(let foo) where foo == .moo:
         return "darmoo"
     case .dar(let foo) where foo == .zoo(let value):
     // how can I access the associated value of foo?
     // This where syntax results in an error - Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly say, it's nested. So nest! Use a switch within the switch. This compiles:

```
func request(with type: Car) -> String {
    switch type {
    case .mar:
        return "mar"
    case .dar(let foo):
        switch foo {
        case .moo: return "darmoo"
        case .zoo(let s): return s
        }
    case .gar:
        return "gar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern matching:

```
switch type {
case .mar:
    return "mar"
case .dar(let foo) where foo == .moo:
    return "darmoo"
case .dar(.moo):
    return "dar: moo"
case let .dar(.zoo(value)):
    return "dar: \(value)"
case .gar:
    return "gar"
}
```

Or, if you want to handle `Foo` in the same manner for `dar` and `gar`, you can bind `foo` in one case:

```
switch type {
case .mar:
    return "mar"
case .dar(let foo) where foo == .moo:
    return "darmoo"
case let .dar(foo), let .gar(foo):
    switch foo {
    case .moo:
        return "moo"
    case let .zoo(value):
        return value
    }
}
```